# Entity Framework schema and connection change at runtime

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I need to do connection and schema changes at runtime using Entity Framework.

I tried the code from this: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663164/changing-schema-name-on-runtime-entity-framework)

I´m using that code:

```
        public EntityConnection SetCurrentEntityConnection(string schemaName, string databaseIPAddress, int databasePort, string userName, string password, string model)
    {
        XmlReader[] MappingReader = new XmlReader[] { XmlReader.Create(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(model + ".msl")) };
        XmlReader[] ConceptualReader = new XmlReader[] { XmlReader.Create(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(model + ".csdl")) };

        var StorageReader = XmlReader.Create(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(model + ".ssdl"));
        XNamespace StorageNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl";

        var StorageXml = XElement.Load(StorageReader);

        foreach (var EntitySet in StorageXml.Descendants(StorageNS + "EntitySet"))
        {
            var SchemaAttribute = EntitySet.Attributes("Schema").FirstOrDefault();
            if (SchemaAttribute != null)
                SchemaAttribute.SetValue(schemaName);
        }
        StorageXml.CreateReader();

        var Workspace = new MetadataWorkspace();
        StoreItemCollection StorageCollection = new StoreItemCollection(new XmlReader[] { StorageXml.CreateReader() });
        EdmItemCollection ConceptualCollection = new EdmItemCollection(ConceptualReader);
        StorageMappingItemCollection MappingCollection = new StorageMappingItemCollection(ConceptualCollection, StorageCollection, MappingReader);
        Workspace.RegisterItemCollection(ConceptualCollection);
        Workspace.RegisterItemCollection(StorageCollection);
        Workspace.RegisterItemCollection(MappingCollection);

        ///
        /// Adjust the connection string
        /// 
        var ConnectionData = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        ConnectionData.Provider = "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client";
        ConnectionData.Metadata = "metadata=res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl";
        ConnectionData.Name = "Entities";

        /// Build the connection string (using Oracle EZ Connection string)
        string conn = "data source=" + userName + "/" + password + "@" + databaseIPAddress + ":" + databasePort + "/" + schemaName ;

        ConnectionData.ProviderConnectionString = conn;


        var Connection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConnectionData.Provider).CreateConnection();
        Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionData.ProviderConnectionString;

        new EntityConnection(Workspace, Connection);
    }
```

I´m running two problems:

Problem 1:
The foreach loop cannot find any EntitySet to change schema.

Problem 2: 
I don´t know how to use the newly created EntityConnection in my EF Application. I normally use:

```
Entity dbContext = new Entity();
```

And start doing queries on my dbContext, but I don´t know how to handle the EntityConnection and what should be done with it. So, what is the relation between the newly created EntityConnection and the original DbContext.

By the way, I´m using DatabaseFirst for Oracle. The DMDX doesn´t generate Entity constructor with connection parameters.

Thanks for any help. This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: Yes... For other reasons I decided to abort EntityFramework and wrote my own SQL template library....