# EF6 dynamically changing a Schema

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database that contains an unknown number of schemas, each schema has the exact same tables.

Is there anyway to change the schema at runtime when creating a new instance dbContext?  I know it's possible to change connection strings at runtime, however the schema names is stored in another database as a table of configurations.

I saw that in EF6 you can set a defaultSchema when overriding `OnModelCreating` however I am not too sure if this is guaranteed to run everytime I use `using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()){}`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do it out of the box but this library can help: http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663164/changing-schema-name-on-runtime-entity-framework