# Modifying schema name in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I would have preferred to simply comment on original posting, but site won't let me.

I used the technique described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663164/changing-schema-name-on-runtime-entity-framework#), but it does not seem to work for Oracle views. They do NOT have a schema attribute. They have instead

```
<EntitySet Name="SAMPLE_VW" 
EntityType="Self.SAMPLE_VW" 
store:Type="Views" 
store:Schema="MYSCHEMA"
```

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution? Any help would be appreciated.