# Changing Entity Framework schema name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, selenium

I'm trying to change the schema name for my app when a schema name is passed as a command line argument.

I have read this solution [Changing schema name on runtime - Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663164/changing-schema-name-on-runtime-entity-framework), but it seems needlessly complicated.

Can anyone tell me whether there is a simpler solution or whether this is the best way to do it?

So just to reiterate, I want to use the default dbo schema name unless a command line argument is passed such as --schema = abc, and in this case I want to use the abc schema. I'm using EF6.

Thanks

Comment: isnt the schema mapped in your context? in this case you could build the model for all schemas, let the database build and call the schema necessary for your query.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found was to just create a separate database and then pass a command line argument (boolean) which allows you to pick which database to use, there are plenty of resources on here on how to change the DB at runtime.