# How to change Entity Framework schema during runtime?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How can you change the `schema` that is defined in the `ssdl` files generated by the Entity Framework at runtime? I understand that this is not support out of the box and I don't want to use any external projects ([like the one suggest here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805816/change-entity-framework-database-schema-at-runtime)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a Code-First model. You need the CTP for that, though.