# Determine Schema and Table Name During EF DbContext POCO Generation

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-5, code-generation, dbcontext

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and the T4 code generation template provided by "EF 5.x DbContext Generator" (database first).  I'm trying to include the DB schema and table name as properties in my entity class, for example:

```
public string _SchemaName {
    get {
        return "SCHEMA NAME HERE";
    }
}

public string _TableName {
    get {
        return "TABLE NAME HERE";
    }
}
```

Has anyone had any luck determining Schema/Table name using the aforementioned code generation template?

Comment: Mind if I ask why? I think the class model should not be concerned with store implementations. Maybe there are ways to achieve what you want with better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @gert-arnold, you shouldn't do that if you want to keep your code clear. Using class attributes may be better way to achieve your goal, but I'm not aware of such attributes in Entity Framework, furthermore, in database first approach (that assumes that you won't change generated classes manually).

Any way I don't think it is possible - not only because no one answered your question in two years, but also because the only places (familiar to me) where you can specify schema are:

- .edmx diagram property (or file: if you open it with text editor, you will see following - pay attention to XML attribute `Schema`)

  ```
  <edmx:Edmx ...>
  ...
      <EntityContainer Name="...StoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="MyTable1" EntityType="Self.MyTable1" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          ... other tables description
      </EntityContainer>
  ...
  </edmx:Edmx>
  ```

  Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307083/how-to-change-the-database-schema-used-by-entity-framework-mysql-database) for more details on this.
- overwrite DbContext's method OnModelCreating(). This works at least in CodeFirst approach.